# Backup of clients' directory to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, backup

We have a machine running Windows Server 2008, and we need to take backup of folder from a desktop on LAN. This folder is **not** shared.

Is there any tool or software to do this, or can a scheduled task be made which should automatically take the backup of that folder date-wise & make a copy on server? Ie can we do it through `Schedule Tasks` option ?

Desktop systems have Windows Vista/Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two options you can pull or push the backup. Personally I would push the backup from the desktops to the Server using the Windows Backup tool (if you do not want to purchase a third party).

I would setup a share called Backup on the Server.

Go to the Desktops both Vista and Windows 7 have the tool. Start Menu > Control Panel > System and Maintenance > Backup and Restore > Set up backup

Then select 'Save on a network' > Type in the share UNC > Next > pick Let me choose rather than recommended and select your folder.

Then set the schedule and you should be good to go!